# Comparing Two Excel with same data in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two excel data source which contains same named column but different data and want to compare that.

For sake of question, I'll take following example:

Excel 1:

`Fruit   Cost
Apple   93
Orange  104
Grape   80
Mango   70`

Excel 2:

`Fruit  Cost
Apple   33
Orange  114
Grape   140
Mango   80`

I want to compare with Fruit on X axis and Cost on Y axis in tableau. I am trying to use line mark, but not sure how to do it. I am new to tableau and just started trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution.

Pull in both Data sources and join on fruit. [image] My Sheets are named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` in the excel files.

Next, create a calculated field named `Difference` with this formula.

```
 [Cost]-[cost (Sheet2)]
```

Then, set up your layout like this:
[image]

From here you can move the pills around to get the layout that works best for you. Welcome to Tableau and hope this helps get you started!